# Firebase Firestore Observe collection documents using SnapshotListener

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uikit

I'm making an app with Swift and UIKit, where I need to fetch a collection of users with pagination.

For my database I use Firebase Firestore.

Here you can see how to fetch the documents, the update function gets the following documents.

```
 internal class UsersViewModel {
     
     //MARK: - Propeties
     @Published public var users: [User] = []
 
     private var lastDocumentSnapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot?
     
     private let pageSize = 25
     
     private var cancelBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()
     
    private var usersListener: [ListenerRegistration?] = []

    {
        members.removeAll()
        
        guard members.isEmpty, !isFetchingData else {return}
        
        self.isFetchingData = true
        self.lastDocumentSnapshot = nil
        self.membersListener.forEach({ $0?.remove() })
        
        let listener = FIRCollections.space_member_requests(space.id).whereField("credential", isEqualTo: "member").order(by: "last_update_tiemstamp", descending: true).listenDocuments(start: nil, limit: pageSize, callBack: fetchCompletion)
        self.membersListener.append(listener)
        updateMembersData()
    }
    
     public func fetchUsers() {
         users.removeAll()
         usersListener.forEach({ $0?.remove() })
         lastDocumentSnapshot = nil

         guard users.isEmpty else {return}
                 
         let listener = FIRCollections.users.listenDocuments(start: nil, limit: pageSize, callBack: fetchCompletion)
         self.usersListener.append(listener)
     }

    private func fetchCompletion(completion: (Result<QuerySnapshot,Error>)) {
        
        if let snapshot = completion.value {
            self.lastDocumentSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last
            
            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { changes in
                
                if changes.type == .added {
                    if !self.users.contains(where: { $0.id == changes.document.documentID}) {
                        FIRUser_Service.shared.getDocument(changes.document.documentID) { result in
                            if let user = result.value {
                                self.users.append(user)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if changes.type == .removed {
                    if let index = self.members.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == changes.document.documentID}) {
                        self.users.remove(at: index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
     
     public func updateUsers() {
         guard let lastDocumentSnapshot = lastDocumentSnapshot else {return}
                 
         let listener = FIRCollections.users.listenDocuments(start: lastDocumentSnapshot, limit: pageSize, callBack: fetchCompletion)
         self.usersListener.append(listener)
     }
 }

extension Query {
    func listenDocuments(start afterDocument: DocumentSnapshot?, limit: Int, callBack: @escaping FIRTypealias_Constants.queryCompletion) -> ListenerRegistration {
        //Gets documents from console
        return self.satrtAfter(afterDocument).limit(to: limit).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    callBack(.failure(error))
                } else if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    callBack(.success(snapshot))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to be able to fetch the documents with pagination but with live updates, so I would need to use snapshotListener, but I don't know how to implement paging with snapshotListener in a collection.

Could someone help me to do the pagination with snapshotListener please.

Answer (score 0):

You would wanna do something like this -

```
public typealias PaginatedCompletionHandler = (([QueryDocumentSnapshot]?, (any Error)?) -> Void)

func fetchInitialFeed(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot?, completion: @escaping PaginatedCompletionHandler) {
    
    guard let lastDoc = document else {
        
        db.collection(FIRCollections.Posts.rawValue)
            .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
            .limit(to: 10)
            .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
                
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else {return}
                
                let documents = snapshot.documents
                
                completion(documents, error)
            }
        return
    }
    
    db.collection(FIRCollections.Posts.rawValue)
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
        .limit(to: 10)
        .start(afterDocument: lastDoc)
        .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {return}
            
            let documents = snapshot.documents
            
            completion(documents, error)
        }
}
```

Get your last document in every call, update your view with it and then in your view when your user scroll to the bottom call the next set of documents.

Make sure you're using a UITableViewController of UICollectionViewController for this btw as they're good for showing long lists of data.

Comment: Thanks but... that wont update in real time. What i want is to use addSnapshotListener, so i get real time updates of my collection.

Comment: just replace getDocuments what that then.

But this is that basic idea of what's to be done.

Comment: also remember that unless you really need to show something updating in real time use getDocuments because a snapshotListener can seriously increase your db read and writes by alot.